# unexpected hover effect on icons

Tags: css

I'm trying to have icons appears over image  when the image is hover in order to click them and for this part it works well but when I hover the icons there is a strange effect.
The icons seems to translate right and left with high speed.
Is there a way to fix that ?

```css
.g-mb-20 {
    margin-bottom: 1.42857rem !important;
}
.g-pos-rel {
    position: relative !important;
}
.o-hidden{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.g-pos-abs {
    position: absolute !important;
}
img + ul.rightFlyOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -24%;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

ul.rightFlyOut li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
 
margin-left: 25px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  
}

ul.rightFlyOut li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut {
  right: 0%;
}

img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut li {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-4 g-mb-30">
<figure class="g-pos-rel o-hidden g-mb-20">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/480/700/4" alt="Image Description">
                      <ul class="rightFlyOut">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                        
                      </ul>
                      </figure>
                      </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you'll need to apply the same rules you have for `img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut` to `ul.rightFlyOut:hover` - have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not strange at all. It's normal behavior.

This happens because you set the icons to appear when hovering on the image. And they do that. BUT when you hover on the icons, you are NO LONGER hovered on the image, so the icons go back to their original position. Keeping your cursor there makes you hover-in and hover-out of the image repeatedly. That's why the icons appear and disappear fast.

**Option 1:** Add the same `img:hover` styles to `ul.rightFlyOut`.

see snippet Below

```css
.g-mb-20 {
  margin-bottom: 1.42857rem !important;
}

.g-pos-rel {
  position: relative !important;
}

.o-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.g-pos-abs {
  position: absolute !important;
}

img + ul.rightFlyOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -24%;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.rightFlyOut li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul.rightFlyOut li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut,
ul.rightFlyOut:hover {
  right: 0%;
}

img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut li,
ul.rightFlyOut li {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-4 g-mb-30">
  <figure class="g-pos-rel o-hidden g-mb-20">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/480/700/4" alt="Image Description">
    <ul class="rightFlyOut">
      <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

    </ul>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

Add hover styles on their parent instead. See snippet

```css
.g-mb-20 {
  margin-bottom: 1.42857rem !important;
}

.g-pos-rel {
  position: relative !important;
}

.o-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.g-pos-abs {
  position: absolute !important;
}

img + ul.rightFlyOut {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -24%;
  width: 30px;
  padding: 1px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.rightFlyOut li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul.rightFlyOut li a {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
}

figure:hover ul.rightFlyOut {
  right: 0%;
}

figure:hover ul.rightFlyOut li{
  margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 col-lg-4 g-mb-30">
  <figure class="g-pos-rel o-hidden g-mb-20">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="http://lorempicsum.com/rio/480/700/4" alt="Image Description">
    <ul class="rightFlyOut">
      <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-inverse fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>

    </ul>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `<img>` and `<ul>` is registered as two different elements. Try wrapping them and check hover on that wrapper instead.

```
.wrapper ul.rightFlyOut {
     right: 0%;
}

.wrapper ul.rightFlyOut li {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

or

```
img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut,
ul.rightFlyOut:hover {
  right: 0%;
}

img:hover + ul.rightFlyOut li,
ul.rightFlyOut:hover li {
  margin-left: 0%;
}
```